# testing $emit in angular directive's controller

Tags: unit-testing, angular-directive

I am a little confused on testing $emit inside of a controller.  The controller I am setting up exists inside of a directive.  I am confused about two parts on setting up the test. How to set up $emit in the test? I am using Jasmine so I did a

```
    spyON(scope, '$emit')
```

My test could not find an object to spy on.  Here is my test.

```
describe('hero Directive', function () {
    var $compile,
        $rootScope,
        scope,
        element,
        ctrl;

    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.module('ha.module.core');
```

I am defining the controller and setting a scope inside the inject.  I compiled the html so that I could use the directive.

```
        angular.mock.inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$controller_) {
            $compile = _$compile_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
```

I assumed the error could be in the controller but it seems to be set up correct.

```
            ctrl = _$controller_('ExploreHeroController', { scope: scope });
```

the directive uses templateUrl I am hoping that I can test with mock out a div and compile it.

```
            var html = '<div explore-hero></div>';
            element = $compile(angular.element(html))(scope);
            scope.$digest();
        });

    });

    describe('directive controller', function () {
        it('should dispatch call $emit with $methodsBound', function () {
            spyOn(scope, '$emit');

            //expect(scope.$emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('$methodsBound');
        });
    });

});
```

the emit sits inside of my directives controller

```
var controller = function($scope) {
    $scope.$emit('$methodsBound');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your directive creates an isolated scope, which is calling $emit,so you need to define this one:

```
 var elementScope;
 //beforeEach 
 el = angular.element('<your-directive></your-directive>');
 $compile(el)(scope);
 scope.$digest(); 
 elementScope = el.isolateScope();

 it('should spy isolated scope', function(){
      spyOn(elementScope, '$emit');
      expect(elementScope.$emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('$methodsBound');
 })
```